# Force some polynomial to have certain roots.

Tags: polynomials

Say we have a third degree polynomial such as $s^3+(a+b)s^2+bs+a$ and we want that polynomial to have two of its three roots at $-1$ and $-2$. Which values of $a$ and $b$ satisfy this condition?

MY ATTEMPT: If the first polynomial is degree two (same degree than the second one) then it's easy, you just make all coefficients equal, and that will lead you to a two equations system. But I've no idea how to proceed when the first polynomial's degree is higher that the second's.

Comment: If $f(s) = as^3+bs^2+cs+d$ (for constants a,b,c,d) has roots $r_1,r_2,r_3$ then we know we can write $f(s) = (s-r_1)(s-r_2)(s-r_3)$. Does this help at all?

Comment: @D.Beec: $f(s)$ in factored form is missing the constant multiple $a$...

Comment: @abiessu Oops, I meant for it to be $f(s) = s^3+bs^2+cs+d$ (similar to how OP's question the $s^3$ term has a coefficient of 1). Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Just substitute $s=-1$ and $s=2$ in $s^3+(a+b)s^2+bs+a$ and get conditions for it to be $0$.

Comment: What if it is a doble root?

Comment: @JorgeMiraPérez, a double root is a common root of $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: Damn, thanks man! I hate it when I lack these math concepts!